# SQL - Update a column for all the rows with random IP address

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have a table `table_user` in my MySQL having a column `ip_address`.

I would like to Update the values of `ip_address` in all the rows with random IP address

Example, like `12.345.678.90` but it must be different in each ip_address row for compatible with the new script code, yesterday I found 312892 records one IP :)

I tried this SQL but didn't work with IP address.

```
UPDATE `table_user` SET `ip_address` = CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING('12.345.678.90', FLOOR(RAND()*26) + 1, 1),
    SUBSTRING('12.345.678.90', FLOOR(RAND()*26) + 1, 1),
    SUBSTRING('12.345.678.90', FLOOR(RAND()*26) + 1, 1),
    SUBSTRING('12.345.678.90', FLOOR(RAND()*26) + 1, 1),
    SUBSTRING('12.345.678.90', FLOOR(RAND()*26) + 1, 1),
    SUBSTRING('12.345.678.90', FLOOR(RAND()*26) + 1, 1)
);
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method should work:

```
UPDATE `table_user` SET `ip_address` = CONCAT(
    TRUNCATE( RAND() * (255 - 1 + 1) + 1, 0 ), '.',
    TRUNCATE( RAND() * (255 - 1 + 1) + 1, 0 ), '.',
    TRUNCATE( RAND() * (255 - 1 + 1) + 1, 0 ), '.',
    TRUNCATE( RAND() * (255 - 1 + 1) + 1, 0 )
)
```

It basically generates numbers from 1 to 255. TRUNCATE function gets rid of decimal numbers (truncate to 0 decimals). RAND function generates numbers from 0 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive).

Comment: Works successfully thanks Vojtěch, I've removed , '.' in the last line, may be useful to someone else.

Comment: Or `UPDATE \`table_user\` SET \`ip_address\` = INET_NTOA(RAND() * 0xFFFFFFFF);`

Comment: I'm not sure what the `255-1+1` is supposed to be.  `256` would be the correct calculation.

Comment: It's just to simplify how to generate random numbers in specific range. From 1 (inclusive) to 255 (inclusive). If you want to change range, you just change +1 and -1 to start value and 255 to max value and +1 near 255 is just to make 255 inclusive. Of course it can be written more easily, but this one is just for easy understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is for MySQL, but if you came here looking for T-SQL code, here it is:

```
select CONCAT(
    round( RAND() * (255 - 1 + 1) + 1, 0 ), '.',
    round( RAND() * (255 - 1 + 1) + 1, 0 ), '.',
    round( RAND() * (255 - 1 + 1) + 1, 0 ), '.',
    round( RAND() * (255 - 1 + 1) + 1, 0 ))
```